# Где и как использовать имя линии/колонки в grid-template-columns?

Tags: css, grid

Сейчас изучаю гриды и немного не понимаю такую вещь, я увидел на сайте что как один из параметров у grid-template-columns(или rows) это имя линии или строки типо:

```
grid-template-columns: [first] 40px [line2] 50px [line3] auto [col4-start];
```

вот, имена здесь указываются в [ ] и у меня такой вопрос, как потом обращаться к этим именам и зачем они нужны? можно ли обратиться к этому имени как к классу или id и изменить например задний фон?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вы можете блока, который содержит контент на странице сделать такой вариант

```
grid-template-columns: [full-start] minmax(15px,1fr) [main-start] minmax(0,930px) [main-end] minmax(15px,1fr) [full-end];
```

А затем добавлять в этот контейнер блоки и выбирать, как они будут отображаться: во всю ширину экрана или занимать максимум 930px. Для этого во внутренних блоках надо добавить параметр, который указывает именованную область, в которой разместить блок:

```
grid-column: full;
```

или

```
grid-column: main;
```

Comment: Но что то я использование имен не вижу нигде

Comment: [full-start] и [full-end] означают начало и конец области с именем "full". Соответсвенно, это используется в строке "grid-column: full;". Вместо "full" и "main" вы можете использовать любое имя.

Comment: А можно использовать это как классы для изменения бг или типо того? или только как вы написали для размера?

Comment: Это именно имена областей в сетке. Вы можете задавать даже двухмерную сетку через [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) с областями и затем указывать в дочерних блоках какую area этот блок должен занять.  

Как-то иначе, кроме как для позиционирования внутри grid данный функционал нельзя использовать.

Comment: Понял, и последний вопрос, что значат тогда вот эти start и end через тире после названий?

Comment: Думаю, вам пора обратиться к документации: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines